# Fitting of Brich-Murnaghan equation of state

Tags: vasp, elasticity, curve-fitting

After performing high-pressure calculations for my ABO4 compounds using the VASP software, I am now interested in fitting the Birch-Murnaghan equation of state to either pressure versus volume or energy versus volume data.

I would appreciate guidance on the best fitting procedure and, if possible, the provision of a Python or MATLAB script for this purpose. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you know Julia, I have a package called [EquationsOfStateOfSolids.jl](https://github.com/MineralsCloud/EquationsOfStateOfSolids.jl) that is designed to do this.

It currently can fit and evaluate $E(V)$, $P(V)$, and $B(V)$ on several equations of state:

1. Murnaghan 1st EOS
2. Birch–Murnaghan EOS family:

   1. Birch–Murnaghan 2nd
   2. Birch–Murnaghan 3rd
   3. Birch–Murnaghan 4th
3. Vinet EOS
4. Poirier–Tarantola EOS family:

   1. Poirier–Tarantola 2nd
   2. Poirier–Tarantola 3rd

It can even reversibly solve the $V$ from a given $P$ or $E$ for certain equations of state.

The documentation is [here](https://mineralscloud.github.io/EquationsOfStateOfSolids.jl/stable/).

The fitting method used is from [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2011.04.016).

Answer (score 3):

Here are some references from my own work:

- a script that reads energy-volume data from a csv file and fits a Vinet equation of state: https://github.com/flokno/tools.mlff/blob/main/mlfftools/scripts/eos_fit_data.py which I used to do the analysis around Fig. 2 and 3 in https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/159/17/174105/2919546/Stress-and-heat-flux-via-automatic-differentiation
- the script is based on the `EquationOfState` class in ASE: https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/tutorials/eos/eos.html
- if you prefer Birch-Murnaghan over Vinet, it is included in ASE: https://gitlab.com/ase/ase/-/blob/master/ase/eos.py?ref_type=heads#L40-50

Things to look out for:

- I would consistently work with energy per atom, which is a normalized quantity
- use a consistent energy baseline (typically the smallest total energy
  of interest) which you subtract from your energies to stabilize the fit